# Apply function on data and get vector/df output in R?

Tags: r, function, dictionary, dataframe, apply

I have the following date:

```
var1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

I have a function that assigns each var1 value a numeric score (0-3).

```
    f(a) --> 2
    f(b) --> 1 

etc...
```

I want to use apply like function to get a data frame with 2 columns:
var1 and score:

```
var1  score
a     1
b     0
c     3
d     3
e     2
f     1
```

I have tried to use vapply and map_dfr but it doesn't work like I have shown.
Please advise how to do this.

P.S

```
For map_dfr: Error: cannot convert object to a data frame
```

Comment: You can use `stack`, i.e. `stack(setNames(lapply(var1, f), var1))[2:1]`

Comment: First set vector var1 as a data frame: `df1 <- as.data.frame(var1)`, then `sapply(df1, function)`

Comment: can you copy and paste your data frame (or a portion therof) and your function?

Comment: I can't use map/apply or any other function of similar functionality to do it in one line of code?

Comment: @Mouad_S The scoring function is huge and it works, meaning that if I do simple sapply I will get a named vector, I need a data frame.

Comment: @akrun will do it now and update.

Comment: `sapply` defaults to a matching data structure, so if you use `sapply` on a data frame column, it will return a vector rather than a list.

Comment: What is the role of set names @akrun? To set the column names?

Comment: @Dr.RichardTennen   We are creating a `named` list and `stack` will convert that to a 2 column data.frame

Comment: @akrun you are genius! It worked!!!!
If possible please write an explanation as an answer and I will accept it. Others should benefit from this brilliant solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your vector to `data.frame`, then use sapply to create the new vector.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(var1)
df1$test <- sapply(df1$var1, function(x) if (x=="a") 1 else 0) 


  var1 test
1    a    1
2    b    0
3    c    0
4    d    0
5    e    0

 str(df1)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ test: num  1 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking help from akrun's solution, this is even simpler

```
f <- function(x) sample(0:3, 1)
var1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

data.frame(cbind(Var1 = var1, Score = lapply(var1,f)))

  Var1 Score
1    a     0
2    b     2
3    c     0
4    d     1
5    e     3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can loop through the `vector` ('var1') apply the function (`f`) to get a `list` of `vector`, set the names of the `vector` with the 'var1' and use `stack` to convert it to a 2 column `data.frame`

```
stack(setNames(lapply(var1, f), var1))[2:1]
```

By default, the `stack` returns column names as 'ind' and 'values'.  We could change that to 'var1' and 'score'

```
setNames(stack(setNames(lapply(var1, f), var1))[2:1], c('var1', 'score'))
```

#### data

```
f <- function(x) sample(0:3, 1)
var1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

Comment: @akrun, can you have a look at my answer?

Comment: Thanks @Hardikgupta